# Why does a cardinality constraint work in a run command but not in a fact?

Tags: alloy

Below is an Alloy representation of two desktops. In the `fact` I specify that the first desktop contains two icons, A and B, and the second desktop contains one icon, A. I'd like to specify that there are exactly two Desktops, so I put this in the fact:

```
#Desktop = 2
```

When I did the `run` command, I got this message: `No instance found`. When I omitted that from the `fact` and instead specified the number of Desktops in the `run` command:

```
run {} but 2 Desktop
```

then the desired instance was generated. Why? Why doesn't it work when I constrain the number of Desktops in the `fact`, but does work when I constrain the number of Desktops in the `run` command?

```
open util/ordering[Desktop]

sig Desktop {
     icons: set Icon
} 

abstract sig Icon {}
one sig A extends Icon {}
one sig B extends Icon {}

fact {
    first.icons = A + B
    first.next.icons = A
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [page 283 of the Alloy Reference](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/book-chapters/alloy-language-reference.pdf), if no explicit bound is specified for a signature and no implicit bound can be found, that signature defaults to *at most* 3 elements. `run {#Desktop = 3}` works by default.

You also have `open util/ordering[Desktop]`. That module starts with `module util/ordering[exactly elem]`, which adds the `exactly` constraint to the scope. This means that the implicit bound is *exactly* 3 elements, so `run {#Desktop = 2}` fails. Adding `run {#Desktop = 2} for 2` changes the implicit bound to 2 elements per signature, so it succeeds.

Comment: Hi @Hovercouch. Thanks once again. Let me see if I understand: One way to constrain the number of members of a sig is when the sig is declared, e.g., one sig Foo {}. The only other way to constrain the number of members of a sig is in the run command, e.g., run for 3 but 1 Foo. The number of members of a sig cannot be constrained in a pred or a fact, e.g., this is illegal: #Foo = 1. Is that right?

Comment: You can constrain the number in a fact. For example, you can do `fact {#Foo = 1}`. Then `run for 3` will allow _up to_ three of each sig, but _exactly_ one Foo. The problem here is that the `ordering` module automatically adds `exactly` to whatever you passed in.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the explanation. So, the conflict is between my claim (in a fact paragraph) that the number of Desktops is 2 whereas the ordering module claims that there are exactly 3 Desktops. Outstanding! Thank you @Hovercouch!